# Creating a simple shell

Tags: c, shell

I'm trying to program a simple shell in C that can execute an executable by just entering the filename. I've tried writing my code which you will see below, but i keep getting the "NO such file or directory error. I'm new to C and I would really love someone to help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

/**
 * main - a super simple shell
 *
 * Return: always 0
 */
int main(void)
{
    char *command[] = {"", NULL};
    size_t len = 0;
    int flag = 1;
    pid_t child_process;
    int status;

    while (flag == 1)
    {
        printf("#fountain-shell$ ");
        getline(&command[0], &len, stdin);
        child_process = fork();
        if (child_process == -1)
        {
            perror("Error:");
            return (1);
        }
        if (child_process == 0)
        {
            if (execve(command[0], command, NULL) == -1)
            {
                perror("Error:");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            wait(&status);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
#cisfun$ /bin/ls
env-environ.c  exec    fork    mypid  ppid    printenv  promptc   shell    wait
env-main.c     exec.c  fork.c  pid.c  ppid.c  prompt    prompt.c  shell.c  wait.c
#cisfun$ ./ppid
5451
#cisfun$ ./ppid
5451
#cisfun$ ^C
```

Comment: Apart from anything else I think `getline(&command[0], &len, stdin);` will result in undefined behaviour.  You initialize `command[0]` with a string literal but from the documentation for `getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);`: `"If *lineptr is not null, the behavior is undefined if *lineptr is not a pointer that can be passed to free..."`.

Comment: The `getline()` function keeps the newline and you don't wait.

Comment: Run your shell with `valgrind` and fix all the errors reported there. It makes no sense to debug this until+unless it is `valgrind`-clean. For starters, this makes no sense: `char *command[] = {"", NULL};` (You need an actual memory backing for the first element instead of a constant `""`.)